# Nakshatras of the Nambudiri Brahmins

Tags: brahmins, sruti, nakshatra

Please help to find out:

1. How exactly do Brahmins Nambudiri define their Nakshatras?
   They define the Nakshatra along the Moon's course in equal sectors along the ecliptic, i.e. in conventional signs of Nakshatras?
   Or they track the Moon in real constellations, i.e. in the Nakshatra asterisms?
2. If they use the signs of the Nakshatras, as in the rest of India, then what Ayanamsha do they use?
3. How many Nakshatras do they use, 27 or 28? The four Vedas and the Brahmanas contain both lists.
4. Do they follow the rule from the second book of Shatapatha Brahmana that Nakshatras are powerless in the daytime and are replaced by the Sun, as a kind of universal "Nakshatra"?

Comment: In the Malayalam calendar, we have only 27 nakshatras (the excluded one is*abhijit*). The nakshatras are thought to be the wives of *Soma* among whom his favourite is *rohini*. The fourth rule, no, nakshatras are believed to govern every aspect of daily life and at all times.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any links to them, so I'll just answer what I know.

▪︎ As in the rest of India, Nakshatras are used in the form of equal fragments of the ecliptic. As it was prescribed in Vedanga Jyotisha, Lagadha.

▪︎ Brahmin astrologers in their Shakha, as in other traditional Vedic Shakhas, use the ayanamsha from Siddhantas (Surya S., Soma S...). And ordinary Keralas can use anything.

▪︎ Use 27 nakshatras as prescribed by Lagadha in his Vedanga Jyotisha.

▪︎ No, the point is that Shatapatha Brahmana is not included in their canon of Shruti texts, it is used in one Shakha in another region of India.